# How to get OpenGL greater than ver 1.1 on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, opengl

I have an app (RViz2 on ROS 2) that refuses to run on my Windows 11 Hyper-V host because the host only has OpenGL 1.1 available - I need it to be 1.5 or better. Normally I go to the graphics card company to solve this, but there is none here.

I have googled a lot, but I don't see a way to get around this. There used to be an option to pass-through to the Host GPU (RemoteFX), but that seems to have been removed after the discovery of some critical security flaws - without replacement.

But there must be a way? Even 1.5 is terribly old - from 2003.

Comment: A problem, since OpenGL is implemented inside your GPU driver.

Comment: RemoteFX was discontinued over 5 years ago. It cannot and should not be used today.

Comment: I get the feeling Hyper-v is being sidelined. For most things Docker is better I guess, but for clean room investigations, nothing beats a VM.